# How to set a predefined message in lblText.steText()

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I want to got the String msg from where Exception is thrown in personAge method so it shows defined error for a person. 
How do I get the message from throw new Invalid..("the message");

to the lable?

This is code in my controler

```
 @FXML
void btnRegister(ActionEvent event) {
    String name = txtName.getText();
    String email = txtEmail.getText();
    String phonenr = txtPhonenr.getText();
    int year = Integer.parseInt(txtYear.getText());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(txtMonth.getText());
    int day = Integer.parseInt(txtDay.getText());

    boolean validateName = PersonValidator.checkName(name);
    boolean validateEmail = PersonValidator.checkEmail(email);
    boolean validatePhonenr = PersonValidator.checkPhonenr(phonenr);
    try{

        PersonAge.personAge(year);
    }catch (InvalidAgeException msg){
        lblResult.setText(msg);
    }

}
```

And this is where exceptions is thrown :

```
public class PersonAge  {
public static int personAge(int year) throws InvalidAgeException {
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Norway"));
    cal.setTime(date);
    int thisYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int age = thisYear - year;

    if(age <=0 || age > 120){
        throw new InvalidAgeException("Age is invalid! Try again");
    }
    return age;
}
```

}

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: `msg.getMessage()`

Comment: How is `InvalidAgeException` defined?

Comment: it extends from exception with method that has attribute super(msg)

Comment: Sorry for that much code. im just not sure which parts of code to include since im still a beginner in coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call getMessage() on the exception: `lblResult.setText(msg.getMessage());`